# Object with multiple fields of the same generic union type

Tags: typescript

I am looking for a way to discriminate a union type as a generic parameter and have the same type on multiple fields of an object

What I mean with that:

```
type A = {
  type: 'A',
  someA: string
}

type B = {
  type: 'B',
  someB: string
}

type Union = A | B

type DatabaseUpdate<T extends Union> =  {
  before: T, // <-- 
  after: T // <-- Those should be the same type, either both A, or both B
}

function test(update: DatabaseUpdate<Union>) {
  if (update.after.type === 'A') {
    console.log(update.before.someA) // Error
  }
}
```

I tried extracting the value based on the `type` because I figured that

```
type Test = Exclude<Union, { type: 'A' }> // this is B
```

works fine. But it still does not seem to be able to figure it out.

```
type $ElementType<T extends {
    [P in K & any]: any;
}, K extends keyof T | number> = T[K];

type DatabaseUpdate<
  T extends Union,
  K = $ElementType<T, 'type'>,
  X = Extract<Union, { type: K }>
> =  {
  before: X,
  after: X
}

function test(update: DatabaseUpdate<Union>) {
  if (update.after.type === 'A') {
    console.log(update.before.someA) // Error
  }
}
```

Ideally I would even be able to have a third field e.g. `type`

```
type DatabaseUpdate<
  T extends Union,
  K = $ElementType<T, 'type'>,
  X = Extract<Union, { type: K }>
> =  {
  type: K,
  before: X,
  after: X
}

// So that I could do 

function test(update: DatabaseUpdate<Union>) {
  if (update.type === 'A') {
    console.log(update.before.someA)
    console.log(update.before.someA)
  }

if (update.type === 'B') {
    console.log(update.before.someB)
    console.log(update.before.someB)
  }
}
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKFBcE8AcFMAICC8C88Dep7ynAXPAOSKEA0W8AzgPYC2siBl4ATgJYB2A5qAL6gQYCAEKoMFXLAKFhZCjXrCmrTjxD8wISfACqHNtQ5jkAH3jCBWofAAiAQ3B2ARncqwd0ACYPYAHgAq8LAAHuCwHJ6UuvqGAHxi4iDYTrAAZtQsUvD+5EnwdqlhLAT+fJapAK4cAMbgBkZhzAAUFV4+BPaOLm4e3mG+evWxAJSJ2Gyp8C1tYQB0BUWz2igrRCSjmHnY1YY0ADaws3vUXNN9hynpmbMKDMMUGhqCcPAAJACiB-Qc4P5CAUFQuFImNsPAANoABXgnHgAGl4AAyfIcSAAXQIdlRAG4+KR4YCwhEogBrWCQaiTQJmDgVWgpFjxND+cFwtG4zTaTrOVzuGawABMvgogRCRJBg0MuWwCLQHy+4V+-xyREkhFi0vgAA0xO9Qiw7LUBjEOPj0DghAQEbxYqAmdhNsk0hkslrNQtYMVtWVNJUanVDDhYMwBWd2rYHDyevyhZKOCNQRMpq1zvNCp6ltYVmhiIQNhRtrtqAcjicw3NLi6bnQ7g8+EA)

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately TypeScript doesn't support "nested" disciminated unions although there's a feature request for it at [ms/TS#18758](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18758).  So just checking `x.y.z` can possibly narrow the apparent type of `x.y` but not the apparent type of `x`.  Maybe a user-defined type guard function would help you?

Comment: Oh that is a bummer, how would I be able to generate a type guard like this ? `function typeGuard(dbItem: DatabaseUpdate<Union>, typeKey: $ElementType<Union, 'type'>): dbItem is DatabaseUpdate2<Union, typeof typeKey> {
  return {} as any
}` but that seems to have the same issue

Comment: You could do [this](https://tsplay.dev/WvY33m) possibly to make a type guard to drill down into objects, if you don't have a discriminant up at the top level of your object.  If you do put a discriminant up there (you call it a "third field") then this *will* work but you need to make your union properly, let me look at it

Comment: Ah I got it `function typeGuard<T extends $ElementType<Union, 'type'>>(dbItem: DatabaseUpdate<Union>, typeKey: T): dbItem is DatabaseUpdate2<Union, T> {
  return {} as any
}` :-) I suppose that would work better than nothing. If you post your solution as an answer I will accept it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: So [this](https://tsplay.dev/W4yg1w) makes your "third field" solution work without any special type guard function.  If you want that as an answer (and not the `nestedDiscriminate` version) I can write that up instead.

Comment: The last one is exactly what I was looking for! You are definitely my hero of the week :-). Yes if you put this into an answer I will accept this.

Comment: To be clear, your `DatabaseUpdate<Union>` was not itself a union, so there was nothing to discriminate.  Something like `{type: "A" | "B", before: A | B, after: A | B}` is not a union even though its properties are unions.  And it can hold a value of type `{type: "A", before: B, after: A}`, since those unions aren't correlated.  You want `DatabaseUpdate<Union>` to be `{type: "A", before: A, after: A} | {type: "B", before: B, after: B}`, an actual union

Comment: Okay I'll write up an answer when I get a chance; might not be in the next three hours though (other duties call)

Comment: Yes, no worries. I am going to bed soon so I will accept it tomorrow or whenever you post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TypeScript, [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) are [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) with a *discriminant property*; each member of the union must have a property with the same key name, and in at least some member the discriminant property value must be of a [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) or other "singleton" type (a type inhabited by exactly one value) like `null` or `undefined`.

If you have a value `u` of a discriminated union type with a discriminant key of `k`, then checking the value of the discriminant property `u.k` will cause the compiler to narrow the apparent type of `u`.

---

Now, your first approach won't work directly because TypeScript doesn't currently support "nested" discriminated unions.  You can only use singleton types to discriminate a union; you cannot use other discriminated union types to discriminate a union.

A union type like `{before: A, after: A} | {before: B, after: B}` is therefore not a discriminated union.  Neither `before` nor `after` are singleton types; they are discriminated unions.  So if you check `update.after.type`, this can only serve to narrow the type of `update.after`.  It does nothing to the apparent type of `update` itself.

There is a feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#18758](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18758) to support nested discriminated unions, but it's not clear when or whether this will be implemented.

There are ways to write a [user-defined type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) which can give a similar result, but it will not be as simple as writing `if (update.after.type === "A")`; it would end up looking something like like `if (nestedDiscriminate(update, ["after", "type"], "A"))`.  I won't go into this because there is another way to proceed here.

---

If you define `DatabaseUpdate<Union>` so that the resulting type is a union with a  discriminant property, then it will be a discriminated union.  So adding a `type` field is a good approach.

Unfortunately, you ran into trouble, because your `DatabaseUpdate<Union>` evaluates to this:

```
type DUU = DatabaseUpdate<Union>;
/* type DUU = {
     type: "A" | "B";
     before: A | B;
    after: A | B; 
   }
*/
```

which is not a union at all, and therefore not a discriminated union.  Each property is a union, but an object-of-unions is not the same as a union-of-objects.  You can see that the difference, because your type allows assignments like this:

```
const oops: DUU = {
  type: "A",
  before: { type: "A", someA: "okay" },
  after: { type: "B", someB: "uh oh" }
}
```

That's valid; the `type` property is `"A"`, which is a valid `"A" | "B"`, and the `after` property is a `B`, which is a valid `A | B`.  Each property of this object type is an independent union type; knowing the value of the `type` property implies nothing about the `before` or `after` properties.

---

We want `DatabaseUpdate<Union>` to itself be a union.  One way to do this is to make `DatabaseUpdate<T>` a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types), which means `DatabaseUpdate<A | B>` will evaluate as `DatabaseUpdate<A> | DatabaseUpdate<B>` (we are *distributing* the `DatabaseUpdate<T>` type across unions in `T`):

```
type DatabaseUpdate<T> = T extends Union ? { 
  type: T['type']
  before: T,
  after: T
} : never;
```

The `T extends Union ? ... : never` construction causes `T` to be split up into its union constituents before evaluating the type, and then the output is unioned back together.

(I also use simplified `DatabaseUpdate` to use a direct [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `T['type']` instead of the ultimately equivalent `$ElementType<T, 'type'>`).

Now let's evaluate `DatabaseUpdate<Union>`:

```
type DUU = DatabaseUpdate<Union>
/* type DUU = {
     type: "A";
     before: A;
     after: A;
   } | {
     type: "B";
     before: B;
     after: B;
   } */
```

Now *this* is a union type, and `type` is a discriminant property.  Suddenly everything works:

```
function test(update: DatabaseUpdate<Union>) {
  if (update.type === 'A') {
    console.log(update.before.someA) // okay
    console.log(update.after.someA) // okay
  } else {
    console.log(update.before.someB) // okay
    console.log(update.after.someB) // okay
  }
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-aYE9wAfhzGo1SGyAFp70gFushxAIKUyEIkKVF5YtusxRkB2i6UgyRwIg4nDdJSmYuis6YkLW3orH2SAcMAEAAG67Gcm5UOKkrStucp7oqHznhSoLarqhEGpU9ImiWFoehmTpZq6rFIV6gpINQ9qKL6SZVI2dqwex8HqFxHQ8RwUlKEgwaDiQizrMA8CkECZDQKQAAU6z7sU8YkbuCoHpRACUDHMNIyz6YZEAAHRinQrlcDwVnCai4bAMIKSORgQhyPZ5GOXBTmFtQFlGkgPl+U5gXBQZoXIZIjmRdFdIjPkGBPNZYYRkI-mJSF7xhRJEUtuomUOnFRUJUFpXFI5qXpVVNVVP2JAiucSh+P15wkMOQRjgAcjpH4LkuK5rqQG6gmKMo7vKDmHocJ5TACKqXtet4Pk+L5vh+X4-n+MgAUBpAgVA4nOtmcI1rJqGgoJGHYbhym0QmDBLaRZlKpRww0YtRGGllJDhZxMWpVDL1CTFkPutDT3yXDSm9aCqnqZpbjaRITXZvqnmUrZSC6ZhEiTYuy7SKuoDFATYzVKaqVpiWaimt0YyphZxPg7FhXFY1yVleFbWiB1MSCRAuXIF5VR1ULSUOeVd3i62kvMF1A6DboOm6cSMM5im+ZIJFZogNQPFVmMiMNkxqbNqIFvqBVVYjBZAxIDeHSu3dor64bT326SNps4WbamlsVsCjbjp3fWuYlk2ZtVWaWx+1m7uKJ73u3hnFWDj1A0lxjpflxjJA3tXNe13XN6DmKtS3B22QtL8m1IGpMzAEIADuwDVFzSAAGpHu3kz-DUsiLLsSAAGJjI5y8z3P47dEgV6TuGkilNkWJSLi2SL0gtSSDGuwUE08zIqfLfZOOYxjwcHAj-aWMaVpFPFKUU003TB4fiT2mEILYAArCAGkxgT1PBUAAykPMYcCNpTzPhfSQV95hPxQdMCQMh5C+g2NsOe3gtjRhSJ0X0alShOlkMdNYM4MB7F0sMUBYCOBwiQHAK6HBqjL0cicMYWFMCvwEBZDgbCGgVAPjiDSuQxjNyum3J+ewDjyxSHNIQfQuhaDYaxDRswOBoKoBg8g19BjDGdGTGYUZljcI7HzVEpNdLflaO0XSaglhRnoG5Us4DIGkFNFZNx1iGjuCELzfKzBvwMCENUGYpxhQ5TyvLGIHJSDrEkO4RYmAnjSW1trdJmTwk+IYMIjAAk-CKCAA)